# Maximize the following function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Maximize

$$f(x) = \left(x^2 + x \left(\frac{N}{P_2} - \frac{P_1}{P_2} x \right) + \left(\frac{N}{P_2} - \frac{P_1}{P_2} x \right)^2 \right)^\alpha$$

where $x \in [0,\frac{N}{P_1}]$. Moreover $P_1, P_2>0$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $N>0$.

---

I think maximizing $f$ is the same as maximizing $$g(x)=(x^2+x(N/P_2-P_1/P_2 x)+(N/P_2-P_1/P_2 x)^2)$$ critical points are the endpoints and points where f'=0, but I do not understand whether this critical points are in the set $x \in [0,N/P_1]$ also to study the sign of f'. Can you help me?

Comment: Note that the polynomial "$\dots$" within $f(x)=(\dots)^\alpha$ is second degree and always has a positive leading coefficient with the given conditions. Hence $f(x)$ must be maximised at one of the endpoints. It is not possible to determine which endpoint is maximal with the given conditions.

Comment: Why candidate points are only the endpoints?

Comment: Because the polynomial inside $f(x)$ is second degree and has a positive leading coefficient. Thus it has a single extremum and it is a minima so it is irrelevant in finding the maximum of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much